# I resign ipa ,when open it , it close application

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, sign

I  download application with my `appleId` from `appStore`, and i resign with `iOS app signer`
,then application installing in  iPhone ,but when i want to run the app, the app open it , after few second it close application.
but if i use `ipa` cracked ( from site [iphonecake](https://www.iphonecake.com))  for resign ,it's not problem and application sign and installing in iPhone, when open it ,it app worked without close application!

Why this happening?i want download app from appStore and resign it, what should i do?!

Comment: Did you check the logs in Xcode? FYI, Connect your device and open Xcode->Devices and select your device logs & run the application.

Answer (score 2):

Please try with this mac application to resign your ipa with different bundle identifier, version or Certificate.
Use distribution certificate and Provisioning for resigning the ipa file.

Follow this: https://github.com/DanTheMan827/ios-app-signer